# Add custom action to Action column on list view

Tags: action, custom-actions

Is it somehow possible to add custom action to Action column on list view?

[image]

Comment: As far as i know you can add custom button in the listview but not the actions.Maybe you need to override and create your own custom list view page.

Answer (score 2):

The closest to what you're trying to achieve would be creating a new formula field on the Opportunity object, set it's return type to text, and in the formula expression enter the HYPERLINK function in order for the formula field to evaluate to html hyperlink () element. The first argument of the HYPERLINK function is the value of the href attribute. So you would want to set this either to some custom VF page which holds the processing logic you need in the custom action, or to a javascript function invoking some backend processing via JS remoting. The second argument of the HYPERLINK function is the text value of the link.
[image: Formula Field evaluating to hyperlink]

Once you're done with the above step, just add your new field to the List View.
[image]